# To fetch the value of a variable using the name of the variable, passed over as a variable value

Tags: java

Using Java,I have to fetch multiple sets of values from an XML file to use in my code. It just so happens that, one of the values I retrieve is the name of a static variable(the value of which is defined in a class file.) I need to find a way to fetch the value of the static variable using the name of the variable I get from the XML file.

Help?

Comment: Not clear. Some code might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to load the class (if necessary; if you have a direct reference to it just use `ClassName.class`), then [`Class#getField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Field#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) for that:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class GetTheStatic {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        String className;
        String fieldName;
        Class cls;
        Field fld;
        String value;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Need [classname] [fieldName]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            className = args[0];
            fieldName = args[1];

            cls = Class.forName(className);
            fld = cls.getField(fieldName);
            value = (String)fld.get(cls);
            System.out.println("Field value is " + value);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming I have this other class:

```
public class TheStatic {
    public static String foo = "bar";
}
```

Then this:

```
java GetTheStatic TheStatic foo
```

outputs

```
Field value is bar
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, as follows:

```
Field f1 = <ClassHavingTheStaticField>.class.getDeclaredField("<staticFieldName>");
Object o = f1.get(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection API, You can get static variable names of a class as follows.

```
Field[] fields = YourClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Then you can iterate them and compare with your xml name values.